# Pope Pius VI and the French Revolution's "Civil Constitution of the Clergy"

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, priests, oaths, french-revolution

The *Civil Constitution of the Clergy* was a law passed during the French Revolution which attempted to make subordinate the Catholic Church in France to the French government.

Among other things, it required that Catholic priests and bishops be elected locally (which included non-Catholics) in an attempt to abolish the authority of the Pope to appoint clergy in France.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_Constitution_of_the_Clergy, *The Pope condemned those who took the oath and went as far as saying that they were absolutely separated from the church.* citation [3], but no page(s) indicated.

QUESTION: Where (papal encyclical, I presume) may I find Pope Pius VI's aforementioned condemnation of those clergy who took the oath required by the *Civic Constitution of the Clergy?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pope Pius VI and the French Revolution's "Civil Constitution of the Clergy"**

On April 13th, 1791 His Holiness Pope Pius VI issued ***“Charitas”***, an encyclical on the **Civil Constitution of the Clergy** and the unfolding situation in revolutionary France. This particular encyclical is quite long.

The whole encyclical can be read [**here**](https://www.papalencyclicals.net/pius06/p6charit.htm).

Comment: Many, many thanks for this information!